# Comparing Values from a HashMap's ArrayList

Tags: java

So I am trying to make a command in Bukkit that will teleport to a new player (one that hasn't played for more than thirty minutes) so they can welcome them. Everything is working great, but I realized that players can spam this command and continuously teleport to the same player to exploit the experience reward you get for welcoming players.

I tried fixing this issue by making a HashMap with a List, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue. Here is my code

```
//Map that is having the issues.
Map<String, List<String>> welcome = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
//This is set to true if a player is matched
boolean found = false;
//This is just initialized before the loop.
Player targetPlayer = player;

//I'm checking if the HashMap contains the player that executed this command
if(!welcome.containsKey(player.getName()))
{
    welcome.put(player.getName(), new ArrayList<String>());
}

//The "welcome" is an ArrayList that contains players that have not been
//online for more than thirty minutes.
for(String offlinePlayer : TheAura.welcome)
{
    //This is to check if player is online.
    Player onlinePlayer = Bukkit.getPlayer(offlinePlayer);
    //Ditto from above.
    if(onlinePlayer != null)
    {
        //This is where the issue lies I believe. It's checking if the
        //HashMap contains the target player.
        if(!welcome.get(player.getName()).contains(onlinePlayer.getName()))
        {
            //Checks the player's mode, ignore
            String mode1 = TheAura.settings.getData().getString(onlinePlayer.getUniqueId() + ".mode");
            //Ditto from above.
            if(mode1.equalsIgnoreCase("easy"))
            {
                //If passed all of this, found is true.
                found = true;
                //Variable from earlier
                targetPlayer = onlinePlayer;
                //Since it found a match, add the target player to the Map's
                //List.
                welcome.get(player.getName()).add(onlinePlayer.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure that I'm missing one tiny little thing and it's just a stupid mistake, but I really can't figure out what's wrong :/ Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

EDIT: Okay, extremely sorry that some of you don't understand. I added comments. I also debugged a bit of this, the Map outputs "{Shortninja66=[Shortninja66]}", which is what confuses me. The map has the same in it, but it does not see it in the if statement?

Imagine the Map works like this:
Shortninja66 (player that has welcomed some players): player1, player2.
Player1 (Another player that has welcomed): Shortninja66.
Hopefully this makes just a bit of sense. I want each player to have their own List of players that they have welcomed..

Comment: Can you please explain how exactly `making a HashMap with a List` is supposed to prevent people from spamming your command?

Comment: You are not asking a question :/ Let's leave aside for a second the bigger context of "being in a game". Cna you state exactly what you want to achieve in terms of maps and lists?

Comment: What is this supposed to do? The variables names are not really clarifying the code. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Edited, sorry for being vague.

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if you break the `for` loop if you've found a player to teleport to? You're currently adding every "offlinePlayer" to the other players list, even if they aren't the "targetPlayer" anymore.

Comment: @Tom I actually did that already in my Eclipse project, good point.

Comment: @user3857694 using map<Player,List> is a good approach, can you say what is your expected result and what do you get?

Comment: @nafas My expected result was to prevent the player from welcoming the same player twice. So if it found a match in "if(!welcome.get(player.getName()).contains(onlinePlayer.getName()))" it would not go any further. However, this did not change anything what so ever. It seems that it passes, even if the list contains the names (I checked by sysout).

Comment: @Tom The way that Bukkit API works, you shouldn't add Player objects to Lists or Maps because it can cause memory leaks. Instead, you add the player's name, therefore a String.

Comment: @Tom I did delete the comment mate, sorry

Comment: @nafas I hope you're sorry >:( .... just kidding, that happens :).

Comment: @user3857694 mate, the code looks very messy and data are comming from all over the place, I suggest you to create a method which takes the targetPlayer and the offline player then narrow down the search to only those two value and other looping and extras should be outside the method. this way you can see where your problem is comming from.

Comment: @nafas I know where everything is coming from, It's just that you guys may not be familiar with Bukkit API. The problem lies with HashMap that has the ArrayList in it. I posted all of the code because people always say that I didn't show enough code. This is the entire method and it is executed when a player does the command. Why would I get the mode of a player that may or may not be online? That is asking for a NPE

Comment: @user3857694 mate, your code is very messy, but just to be sure, is it "exactly" how your code looks like?

Comment: @nafas This is a snippit from the class. All of the code you see is the code that is incorporated with the problem. Except, the problem is only the HashMap. I really don't get how this is "messy", I asked on Bukkit and Spigot forums and no one complains.

Comment: @user3857694 here you go mate, look at the answer.

Answer (score 0):

ok, let's go through the code :

1-  creating a new hashMap

```
Map<String, List<String>> welcome = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

<-- each time this code is run creating new HashMap?

2-  creating a new list for the player

```
if(!welcome.containsKey(player.getName()))
{
    welcome.put(player.getName(), new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

<-- now at this point welcome map is definitely empty so is the array that player is linked to.

3- adding a player to the list of the player

```
  if(mode1.equalsIgnoreCase("easy"))
        {
            //If passed all of this, found is true.
            found = true;
            //Variable from earlier
            targetPlayer = onlinePlayer;
            //Since it found a match, add the target player to the Map's
            //List.
            welcome.get(player.getName()).add(onlinePlayer.getName());
        }
```

<-- it will only add the player if `mode1 is "easy"`. there is a possible loss here

From this code I see at least 3 point where the errors could occur. Therefore, the code is messy and needs to revised based on the requirements.

Since I don't know the full requirements the only help I can offer at this point is to `encapsulate` your code into smaller methods.

Comment: It is NOT created each time the command is called, I put that Map there so you can see what the Map has in it, sorry for bad placement.

The mode IS easy, that is the default mode. I don't want them to have people teleporting to them if they are in any mode besides easy. I've revised this code many times and the ONLY problem lies with the Map, hence why I titled the question "Comparing Values from a HashMap's ArrayList".

Comment: @user3857694 in programming sometimes slight misplacement of a line will result in complete failiure. how do you expect other people understand the problem if "that" is not your actual code.

Comment: I understand what you are saying completely, that is why I said, "I'm sure that I'm missing one tiny little thing and it's just a stupid mistake, but I really can't figure out what's wrong," in my original post. If you want, I can post the entire class. But I really am just perplexed by the Map not working despite having input from many people (I have posted on three other forums) and revising the code over and over. Thank you for your time and assistance so far.

Comment: @user3857694 mate, just a note of advice, I definitely recommend you to encapsulate your program better. for example if you are using a Map, make sure there is only one specific single (set) method(s) it can be modified. if you do that, you'll see the problem will pop out by itself

Answer (score 0):

At long last, I answered my problem.

I revised my code and encapsulated some of it, separating it into smaller methods like @nafas suggested. However, my problem was not lying in the code itself, but the method of the code I suppose. Bukkit API typically uses one method that is usually like "public boolean onCommand(..." but I used an interface so I could separate each command into their own class to make it nice and neat. When I switched my code over to the boolean method, it worked. The only difference was that I was returning "true" when a player was found.

I find this a bit weird but I guess it makes sense. Thank you to all that bothered to assist me!